# Behavior difference in a for each in loop and for loop over Vectors in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, vector, for-loop, foreach

I have two loops:

```
var theVector:Vector.<MyClass>;

for each (var myClassItem:MyClass in theVector)
{
    myClassItem.methodInMyClass();
}

for (var i:int = 0; i < theVector.length; i++)
{
    theVector[i].methodInMyClass();
}
```

I had expected both to function the same. However, on compile, the first loop (for each in) throws an error that `methodInMyClass` does not exist. Is this something documented that I just haven't been able to find? I was under the impression that the for each in loop would work fine.

Also, just realized this works:

```
for each (var myClassItem:MyClass in theVector)
{
    myClassItem['methodInMyClass']();
}
```

I'm using FlashDevelop to compile and I'm starting to wonder if that could be the issue.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. You are certain that MyClass actually has a public function methodInMyClass()? If you don't initialize the Vector (as is the case in your code), you'll get a nullpointer in the second loop though.

Comment: let me clarify, `theVector` is being assigned like this:
`theVector = Service.getMyClassVector()`, which would/should be an initialized Vector. But, that kind of error would be on runtime, correct?

Comment: Also, when breaking in the loop, `myClassItem` has the correct item in it. (if i comment out the line with `methodInMyClass` in order to compile.)

Comment: The nullpointer would be at runtime, yes. About the new 'anonymous' option: does it just compile or is the method also actually executed at runtime? I don't know FlashDevelop, but I find it hard to believe it wouldn't support 'for each' loops. Have you tried the same with an Array instead of a Vector (mind you, the normal 'for' loop will not compile without casting then)? Perhaps you have two definitions of MyClass that are getting mixed up?

Comment: It compiles and runs. I'm working in code that is "maintenance" so I'm not familiar enough with it to check if there's a namespace conflict. I'm going to run the tests again in the Flash and FlashBuilder IDE's to see if there is a difference.

Comment: Can you check the object type with
describeType(myClassItem) ?